# Jboss7 MDB MailListener to a mail redopurce adapter

Tags: jakarta-mail, jboss7.x, ear, message-driven-bean, seam2

I'm porting a seam2/hibernate ear app to jboss7.1.1FINAL

I've included in ear\lib the jar mail-ra.jar that contains sem interfaces I neaded.

But it looks like that the mail-ra.jar lib is not find during the deploy I got the error above

Any hints?

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.ra.mail-ra (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."4pm_ee_services-ear.ear"."4pm_ee_services-ejb.jar".component.MailListenerMDB.CREATE] 

16:25:57,299 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"4pm_ee_services-ear.ear\".\"4pm_ee_services-ejb.jar\".component.MailListenerMDB.CREATEjboss.ra.mail-raMissing[jboss.deployment.subunit.\"4pm_ee_services-ear.ear\".\"4pm_ee_services-ejb.jar\".component.MailListenerMDB.CREATEjboss.ra.mail-ra]"]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

@simonC its seems you standalone.xml is jndi-name is wrong it should be like this

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/mobeeaAirtimeDatasource" pool-name="mobeeaAirtimeDatasource_pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
     <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mobee</connection-url>
    <driver>com.oracle</driver>
       <security>
                 <user-name>airtimeuser</user-name>
                   <password>mobeepasswd</password>
               </security>
       </datasource>
```

Comment: hmm it's not a datasource name, it is a resource adapter name, the porblem is that MDB MailListener config in jboss7 has changed from jboss5 ... there was a mail-ra.rar deployed now in jboss7 it looks diferent and i'm still searching for the solution

Comment: @simonC Ok.Im also doing now changing seam 2 application jboss4.2.2 to jboss7.1.1Final , in jboss7.1.1 Final is it possible to declare more then persistence-unit in persistence.xml